# Plot smooth cumulative distribution function using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics

How is it possible to make the following [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF) curve smoother?

Here's my code, using [cdfplot](http://www.mathworks.se/help/toolbox/stats/cdfplot.html):

```
clear all; 
close all;
y = [0.75862069 0.666666667 0.882352941 0.875 0.736842105 0.566666667 0.703703704 0.6 0 0.730769231 0.714285714 0.625 0.675 0.693877551 0.731707317 0.558823529 0.679245283 0.740740741 0.785714286 0.789473684 0.615384615 0.6 0.739130435 0.576923077 0 0.75];
cdfplot(y)
```

The plot looks like:

[image]

Comment: What have you done in attempts to figure out the problem?

Comment: yea:data = [1 1 1 4 5]; %# Sample data
p1 = cdf('Normal',data,0,1);
plot(p1);

Comment: This appears to be an empirical CDF and therefore will not typically be smooth unless altered.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = [1 2 2 3 4];
dsum = sum(data);
normalized_data = data/dsum;

cdf = data;

for i = 1:length(data)
    cdf(i) = sum(normalized_data(1:i));
end

plot(cdf);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [2 1 4 2 3];
sdata = sort(data);
plot(sdata,(0.5:length(sdata))./length(sdata),'-');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `ecdf`:

```
[f,x] = ecdf(y);
plot(x,f);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one method. But I consider it as a kind of cheating. Use it with your own responsibility. 
you can try `cdfplot([x,x+a*randn(length(x),1)]).` You can play with parameter `a`, but I suggest you to use value around 0.5. Cheers.